# How to make call to specific phone number inside Twilio Studio flow?

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio

I trigger studio flow using REST API along with From and To parameters. In case of To number does not answer or call is failed, I need to try another number. How can I implement this ? Make Outgoing Call widget does not let modifying To parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

A Studio flow execution is intended to represent one call, either the incoming one from the incoming call trigger or an outbound one from the REST Trigger. So, you can't trigger a new call to a different number from within the same flow.

What you could do instead is use a [Function Widget](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/run-function) to call a [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) that then triggers a new Studio flow execution with a new `To` number.